# How to control memory consumption in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, memory, memory-management

I have been looking for a solution to the memory consumption in windows 10. Always when the system boots or while the windows is running the task manager shows almost 100% of disk/memory or both are consumed already.

I have tried to resolve it via stopping and turning the startup of most of the services as `manual` via `services.msc` that includes unnecessary services that run on startup, superfetch (that is usually used to speed up the system rather consuming more memory so had to change its startup as manual), windows store service and even cortana via alternatively renaming the cortana folder, plus some manual tasks of cleaning up the temp, prefetch, etc folders.

Also, I have partitioned my drives with the main C: drive having half of the disk as free space. Even after doing so much one or the other system process is consuming the whole disk/ram memory on startup/boot plus when I try to open chrome then chrome adds several uncontrolled processes that lead to more memory consumption.

So, I would really appreciate if anyone could help out on this.

Comment: Sounds like you're mixing up RAM usage, disk usage and possibly disk throughput. RAM is used to store data that is currently processed. Disk is used to store persistent data, ie. programs, documents, all kinds of files. Disk has limited space, but also limited throughput, ie. it can read and write data at limited speed. Which of the three are you talking about?

Comment: I know the running memory is RAM and the backend storage memory is your disk memory. The memory I am as of now concerned is especially RAM that slows down the execution

Comment: The goal of any exercise like this is not to reduce RAM usage. Reducing RAM usage means the machine has to work harder or slower to achieve the same end result. Empty RAM is wasted RAM. The OS knows what it's doing & why. Just let it. Don't try to out-guess things, you'll just make them worse… disabling prefetch to speed up your machine is like draining your car's gas tank to save weight.

Comment: I know empty ram is wastage ram. I am not asking so that I could free the ram completely but there are several useful applications like Oracle Sql Developer, VMware, eclipse with java etc. Do you think any of the processes will be able to run smoothly with having such high memory consumption already by system processes. I have not disabled prefetch that is the time after system has created some dump files in the prefetch folder I had remove the same from prefetch folder npthing else

Comment: If you are truly RAM-starved, & that list would indicate you could be, then the only way to speed those up is buy more RAM. Consider 16GB bare minimum if you want to run VMs effectively.

Comment: I was not specific to especially VMware but others too. Such memory consumption doesnt let me to atleast run a command line sql and hangs more often and what is the use of having a 1 TB disk memory when you cannot perform your normal processes with a 4gb ram. Also, I am not disabling all the system processes but some processes like some process for running Feedback Hub Windows Store applications, Cortana etc. but I had to change Cortana to its default because the search and cortana both were clubbed

Comment: You can't do **anything** with 4GB RAM these days. You can barely run a browser & the OS on 4GB. You need more RAM. Start at 16GB or more, don't even think about 8.

Comment: That seems the last option but I still think there is atleast one process which is leading to high memory consumption and that process is not critical but still a system's process

Comment: Windows will start to page at about 50% RAM usage.. these days with only 4GB, that's pretty much from boot time. If you have an HD rather than SSD, then your machine is just going to crawl. If you have SSD it will be better, but paging even to SSD is literally a thousand times slower than having sufficient RAM in the first place.

Comment: If you could please move on with getting more ram as I had already reduced the usage somewhat by atleast 2-3 % by disabling superfetch. Its not the case that whole 4gb ram will be utilised by system processes. Sometimes you should be able to check what processes needs to be controlled like I din find the windows store service was adding to my windows memory consumption so i disabled it. Also, I am not randomly disabling it I see what that service actually does and then I decide plus the Windows itself gives you a warning if its a critical process. I hope that clears out

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of _Resource Monitor_’s “Memory” view.

Comment: I'll restate this: **nowadays 4 GB is just not enough**. Simply getting more RAM will be more productive than spending hours to reduce RAM usage by 2-3% at the cost of performance. This amount of RAM is not sufficient to do anything with modern software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many processes running simultaneously for 4 GB RAM.

- Open Task Manager.
- On the *Details* tab, sort by *Memory (active working set)*.
- See which processes are using up RAM and prioritize. Do you need all running at once?
- If Services are an issue, see [Black Viper's Windows 10 Service Configurations](http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-10-service-configurations/), which suggest some that can safely be disabled (and warns of others that should *never* be stopped or disabled).
- Windows 10 spends a lot of time, tying up the network and CPU cycles, reporting back to Microsoft. Some usage can be saved by getting rid of live tiles, advertising, feedback, etc. You can do that manually, or using a third-party tool such as [O&O Software's ShutUp10](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10).

That said, during boot, the system is busy checking for updates, verifying files with the antimalware application and other tasks. *Expect* a Windows machine to be lethargic after a cold boot. You have some other choices:

- Use Hibernate (or Sleep), which start *much* faster. It takes seven minutes for Windows cold boot to complete on one machine I use, and ~one minute to come back from hibernation.
- Use another OS. On that same machine, Linux starts from cold boot in less than two minutes.

Comment: That is the basic step to see memorywise order the processes dont you think at first I would have done it already. Do you know RunTimeBroker service /wsapp service for app deployment? The reason I am asking is there is an application called Feedback Hub or People which is of no use for me but that application wasnt showing a direct service instead in its subtree i saw RuntimeBroker is this an isolated service or its clubbed with other services as in cortana search and cortana service are clubbed so I tried to alternatively disable cortana itreducedthememorysmwhat but searchdinwork

Comment: So I had to change cortana to default again

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja, it is difficult to understand *what* you've done unless you explicitly state it. Some tips on disabling Services and other usage wasters have been added. As for Runtime Broker, that information is provided by MS: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027837/windows-10-runtime-broker-is-using-too-much-memory  BTW, what is "clubbed"?

Comment: By clubbed I meant two processes index search and cortana have been merged in win 10 you cannot perform a search without cortana both work together

Comment: Your 4th point is somewhat near to my problem rest I dont think and the boot you are talking about that windows critical services occupies hard disk space almost upto 100%